How to read the tags of a enip server ('1756-L61/B LOGIX5561') build using cpppo via pycomm3 logix driver
I have a build a Logix simulator server which changes the values of tags every 10 sec using cpppo and when I am trying to read the tags of the server using, pycomm3 logix driver, it is throwing an error.
"pycomm3.exceptions.ResponseError: failed to get by attribute list".
Error message:

Server log:

By using pylogix client, I was able to read the tags. Why am I unable to read the tags using pycomm3 logix driver?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Can you show your command-line instruction or python code on the cpppo side?
